# Что следует прописать в gradle,чтобы он при сборке проекта включал нужные библиотеки?

Tags: java, gradle

После некоторого опыта работы с gradle-ом, я выяснил,что при сборки jar файла он некладет в этот файл библиотеки, которые использовались при написании кода. На форуме я видел,что есть плагины,или скрипты с использованием которох, при сборке джарника gradle скачивает библиотеки, указанные в dependencies и укладывает их в jar файл вместе с остальными элементами проекта, что при запуске jar-файла дает возможность не указывать пути к этим самым библиотекам. Существуют ли такие вещи и где об этом можно прочитать?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вариант. в build-файле прописал следующее:

```
group 'test'
version '2.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "testpack.JClass"
sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.53.0'

}


jar {

    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Вдруг, кому-то пригодится...